# Stream Playback Error?

Tags: playback, audio-streaming

When listening to a radio station, such as http://www.wgst.com, sometimes after a while I get a modal error box with a "Stream Playback Error"allowing only an OK response. What causes this and how can I fix/repair it?

Ross

Answer (score 0):

What media player are you using to playback the stream? Are you just using the built-in player at the website?

What browser and operating system are you using?

"Stream playback error" usually just means that your internet connection was disrupted long enough for the buffer to run out... this can be for more reasons than I can count (it may be the remote server, it may be your system, or something in between).

Comment: Win7  and FF or IE or Chrome